# Determining if an SSL cert is from cloudflare

Tags: linux, ssl, curl, cloudflare

I have got a lot of domains. I use basic monitoring script, which checks expiration date of ssl certificate. But a few of my domains use default cloudflare cert.

How to determine and reject domains which use cloudflare built-in SSL certificate?

Comment: What are you starting with? You have noted that you are using `curl` on Linux, how are you using that? Have you already extracted the certificate, or even the certificate chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make a simple bash script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

x=$(openssl x509 -in cert.pem -text | grep -i cloudflare)

if [ "$x" != "" ]; then
  # code for rejecting
else
  # code for ok
fi
```

Comment: If you replace 'cert.pem' with $1 then you can just issue ./script.sh name-of-cert.pem